# Overload data type rendering in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there an easy way to overload data type rendering in Rails?

For example having Boolean rendered as:

```
true  #=> 
false #=>
```

or Integer as:

```
6  #=> 'six'
10 #=> 'ten'
```

I was hoping for something like there is http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models for column names, there would be something programatic for  data type of a column.

This is pretty close https://blog.arkency.com/2016/03/custom-typecasting-with-activerecord-virtus-and-dry-types/ . But something built-in would be nicer ;)

Comment: What do you mean by _"rendering"_?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by overwriting a class's `to_s` method, for example:

```
class TrueClass
  def to_s
    'foo' 
  end
end

puts true #=> 'foo'
```

I'm not sure this will always be a great idea, but that's how it can be done :)

For the integers, you'd need to write something to convert them, or use a gem like [numbers_and_words](https://github.com/kslazarev/numbers_and_words), but the above approach would still apply.

Hope that gets you in the right direction! Let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that you can override #inspect for an other representation for the console output. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-inspect

Comment: "I'm not sure this will always be a great idea" - I'm not sure this is a great idea at all (to put it mildly) :)

Comment: Yup, I'd tend to use your approach @SergioTulentsev, but thought this, technically, answered the question (without any further context for the problem).

Comment: This is working solution, but as few of you mention it's probably not a good idea, because this would be happening everywhere. I would be happy with views. I was hoping for something like there is http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models for column names, there would be something programatic for  data type of a column.

Comment: Fair enough @Mailo, sounds sensible. Thanks for the update - will have a think with the added info.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy way to overload data type rendering in Rails?

Pass your data through a rendering helper:

```
class ApplicationHelper
  # "mf" for my_format
  def mf(value)
    case value
    when true
      ''
    when false
      ''
    when Integer
      value.to_english_words # or something like that
    else
      value # unchanged
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in the views.

```
<%= mf user.approved? %>
<%= mf user.age %>
```

Comment: This is what I currently have. I was hoping for something more built-in

Comment: @Mailo: the other answer offerst a more "built-in" solution. You don't want that. :)

Comment: The other solution is changing Ruby type a would be happy with adjusting Rails reflection of DB type ;)